# Django: How to follow ForeignKey in unique_together constraint?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, unique, django-orm

I have three Django Models:

- a `Property` Model, most importantly having a `slug` field;
- a `Collection` Model; and
- a `PropertyCollectionRelationship` Model.

The last model models a ManyToMany relationship between the other two and is used as an explicit `through` of a ManyToManyField.

```py
from django.db import models

class Property(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    collections = models.ManyToManyField('Collection', blank=True, through='PropertyCollectionRelationship')
    # ... other unimportant stuff omitted ...

class Collection(models.Model):
    pass
    # ... lots of stuff omitted ...

class PropertyCollectionRelationship(models.Model):
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coll = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to add a uniqueness constraint which ensures that each collection has at most one property with any given slug. I tried to express this via a unique_together option in the Model Meta:

```py
class PropertyCollectionRelationship(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['coll', 'prop__slug']]
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coll = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This resulted in the following System Check Error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
myapp.PropertyCollectionRelationship: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'prop__slug'.
```

How, if at all, can I achieve such a constraint?

**Edit:** As suggested below I could set `unique=True` on the `slug` field, however my use case requires different properties with the same slug to coexist.

Comment: Why don't you define `unique_together = [['coll', 'prop']]`. Normally a `slug` is *unique* per instance so by making `coll, prop` unique, that will have the same implications.

Comment: Yes, each property has a unique slug, but there may be multiple properties with the same slug. 

`
C0 := Collection()
C1 := Collection()

P1 := Property(slug='a')
P2 := Property(slug='a')
`

But `unique_together = ['prop', 'coll']`
would allow `[(C0, P1), (C0, P2)]` which I want to forbid.

Comment: but since the slug is unique, you can not make two properties with `slug='a'`. So the database will prevent that.

Comment: I was under the impression that unique=True was something that had to be explicitly set.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield doesn't mention anything special for a SlugField. I guess I should edit the question and make it a non-unique CharField instead.

Comment: @TomWieseling: it is correct that you need to set it explicitly. I was only asking if in your use case-the slug field is unique. If that is the case, the `unique_together` will imply that the slugs are unique.

Comment: I see, however my use case explicitly has situations where two properties with the same slug exist. They are just associated to different Collections.

Comment: Hi @TomWiesing, have you found a solution for this? I am stuck with exactly the same problem: Enforcing uniqueness over fields and foreign key fields. I get the same error message. Django 5.0, Python 3.11.4